Capture audio from an INMP441 MEMS mic using ATmega328P
I'm trying to capture one sample from an INMP441 MEMS mic using an ATmega328P on Arduino Uno, and send that to my PC over USART. I have the following circuit set up.

Now, I'm trying to use the SPI module as an I2S to capture the sample.
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/setbaud.h>

#define SPI_SS   PB2
#define SPI_SCK  PB5
#define SPI_MOSI PB3

// start SPI in master mode with clock set to 16MHz/8 = 2MHz.
static inline void spi_init(void)
{
    DDRB = (1 << SPI_SS) | (1 << SPI_SCK) | (1 << SPI_MOSI);    
    SPCR = (1 << SPE) | (1 << MSTR) | (1 << SPR0) | (1 << SPI2X);
}

static inline void usart_init(void)
{
    UBRR0H = UBRRH_VALUE;
    UBRR0L = UBRRL_VALUE;
#if USE_2X
    UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);
#else
    UCSR0A &= ~(1 << U2X0);
#endif
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXEN0) | (1 << RXEN0);
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

static inline void usart_send(char data)
{
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)))
        ;
    UDR0 = data;
}

static inline void usart_send_bits(unsigned char c)
{
    int i;
    unsigned char x;

    for (i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        x = c & (1 << i);
        usart_send(x > 0 ? '1' : '0');
    }

    usart_send('\r');
    usart_send('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char buf[4];

    spi_init();
    usart_init();

    // MOSI as WS, read 4 bytes from L-channel
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        SPDR = 0;
        while (!(SPSR & (1 << SPIF)))
            ;
        buf[i] = SPDR;
    }

    usart_send_bits(buf[0]);
    usart_send_bits(buf[1]);
    usart_send_bits(buf[2]);
    usart_send_bits(buf[3]);

    for (;;)
        ;

    return 0;
}

When I run this, all I see a 0s:
00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000

The Makefile:
CC = avr-gcc
MCU = atmega328p
TARGET = inmp

SRC = main.c
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)

CFLAGS = -std=gnu99
CFLAGS += -Os
CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -mmcu=$(MCU)
CFLAGS += -DBAUD=115200
CFLAGS += -DF_CPU=16000000UL
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections

LDFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU)
LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections

HEX_FLAGS = -O ihex
HEX_FLAGS += -j .text -j .data

AVRDUDE_FLAGS = -p $(MCU)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += -c arduino
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += -P /dev/cuaU0
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += -D -U

%.o: %.c
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

elf: $(OBJ)
     $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $(TARGET).elf

hex: elf
     avr-objcopy $(HEX_FLAGS) $(TARGET).elf $(TARGET).hex

upload: hex
     avrdude $(AVRDUDE_FLAGS) flash:w:$(TARGET).hex:i

.PHONY: clean

clean:
     rm *.o *.elf *.hex 


CHIPEN of INMP441? It's not exposed as a pin on mine. I assumed when VDD is high mic is enabled. Damn, I didn't think of the initial power up and the continuous clock.I guess I can't use SPI this way then.

If you're using a breakout board, then check the schematic - it'll probably handle CHIPEN for you.


When I run this, all I see a 0s

Yes, and the datasheet confirms this behaviour:

The microphones have zero output for the first 218 SCK clock cycles (85ms with SCK at 3.072 MHz) following power-up.

I2S is not like SPI - you are generally (always?) required to provide a continuous and stable clock alongside the link.
See also the following excerpts:

The microphone becomes operational 218 clock cycles (85 ms with SCK at 3.072 MHz) after initial power-up.


The microphone enters standby mode when the serial-data clock SCK stops and CHIPEN is high.


Normal operation resumes 214 clock cycles (5 ms with SCK at 3.072 MHz) after SCK restarts.

The definition of "stops" is not explicitly mentioned, but based on the timing specifications listed, the fSCK (SCK frequency) is listed with a minimum of 500 kHz, so anything slower than this will likely be considered "stopped" - i.e: the signal being static for ~2µs.


Based on the above, an ATmega328p isn't a good choice for interfacing with I2S - you can potentially get it working using a timer and/or interrupts to produce the clock, and the SPI peripheral in "slave" mode (you'll need to get imaginative for 32-bit transfers, and it may not be possible)... ultimately, you may well need to "bit-bang" the interface... (I've seen it done on an AVR!)
Be aware that 218 clock cycles will take a while at lower frequencies... ~524.3ms at 500 kHz.
Note also that your chosen microphone is only rated for ~3.3v operation, while the Arduino has 5v I/O!

Thank you for the tip on using the slave mode, I will try it. Is there any chance at all of making it work if I sent extra zeros on WS initially to cover the ~85ms?

You don't need to "send zeroes" to the microphone... it's only got an ouput. You need to generate a clock signal (between 500 kHz and 3.2 MHz), and toggle the WS signal (between 7.8 kHz and 50 kHz, depending on the clock frequency - Fws = Fclk / 32 / 2)... you'll then start getting data once the mic is up and running.

Note also that the data becomes valid one bit after the WS signal changes.

@Attie the use of MOSI data as WS to mic is rather interesting. And you can send any bit pattern you want so you can shift the MOSI bit pattern by one to align the received data to bytes. If only the mic could handle the 5V signals without damage.

Not going to work for many reasons.
First of all, you have connected a mic with 3.3V IO interface to an MCU with 5V  IO interface. The MCU specifies that minimum input high voltage is 0.7*Vcc or 3.5V, so 3.3V output does not have to work.
Also the 5V clock and MOSI output you use for WS are too much for the mic and it needs to clamp 5V IO to 3.3V supply through protection diodes, so it may not work or it can even cause damage.
Second thing is that the protocol is incorrect. You must transfer 32 bits with WS low and 32 bits WS high. You never even toggle the WS and never transfer the bits you leave unused.
Also it says on the data sheet that the mic needs 262144 clocks to start up and output anything. Of course it needs the bit clock and the WS clock as per the protocol.
So you cannot just start up your MCU and send 32 clocks while reading data back. It will not work.
Also the clocks need to be continuous like for any I2S device. So you cannot send a burst of clocks with SPI and then pause while you transfer data out via UART.
Also the clocks need to be continuous and stable, and there is no guarantee that AVRs can output continuous clocks. At least in earlier Atmega models each 8-bit transfer took 9 clocks of time even if 8 clock pulses were generated.
So it might be impossible to connect an I2S mic to an ATmega328p AVR in a way that it works or is sensible. You need a large enough MCU with an actual I2S interface, so your mic project already outgrew from the 8-bit Arduinos.

Thanks for taking the time to point out the issues one by one. I  toggled the WS for 32 more bits, but omitted it in the code sample. I'm waiting for a bigger MCU to arrive. I thought I might as well try this while waiting. Thought at least I'd learn something that way. Looks like I overlooked many things, but I still have sometime to try and address those points somehow.

@kovac Well don't omit important stuff out required for correct operation.

Good point re 5v Arduino I/O ... I'd forgotten all about that!
